# How can I prevent headless chrome from caching cookies?

Tags: c#, sqlite, selenium, cookies, google-chrome-headless

I'm running an automation script in selenium C# with a headless chrome instance.

```
    var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("disable-gpu");
    chromeOptions.AddArgument("disable-cache");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(".",chromeOptions);
```

I am trying to track all cookies including ones sent by 3rd party javascripts. More importantly, I'm trying to track cookies within one domain. So for example, I want to differentiate cookies set on www.xyz.com/index and cookies set on www.xyz.com/store.

I'm currently trying to do this by navigating to www.xyz.com/index then querying the SQLite database in chrome's temporary data folder, then navigating to www.xyz.com/store and again querying the SQLite database.

The problem is that chrome doesn't save cookies to this database as soon as you navigate to a site. It seems to cache the cookies and then saves them all at once every 30 or so seconds.

Is there any way I can force chrome not to hold on to the cookies for so long? Ideally I would want chrome to save cookies to the SQLite database as soon as I navigate to the site.

Comment: try with --disk-cache-dir=null

Answer (score 1):

You may use manage().getCookies() and its related methods to get the cookie information, like name, path, expiry or domain etc. You should be able to get the cookie information as soon as it is saved.

Comment: That would only get 1st party cookies. I need to record 3rd party cookies that result from 3rd party JavaScript execution.